# How to overlay pins icons to background img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dictionary, bootstrap-5

I am trying to place pins on top of an image, simulating a map. My idea is that each hover displays an address, as I show in the image.
[image]

I have searched the internet if there is a jQuery plugin for this, I have found topoJSON or leafletjs, however, these plugins are used to create real maps, with functions like zoom and coordinate handling, I don't need something so complicated.

Is there a recommended plugin to achieve this effect? Or, any tricks I can do to achieve this? Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Use css :hover and make your image show. For example, if this is your pin "<div class="pin"><img class="image" src="image.jpg"></div>", use css like "div.pin > img.image { display: none } div.pin:hover > img.image { display: inline; }"

Comment: are these pins dynamic? I assume they are. Do you have gps data for each one? you might be able to simulate a left:%, top:% position from the lat and lon - I'll bet someone has written something like that. Google!  As for the hover, there are tooltip scripts abound, especially for bootstrap.

Comment: For now I only have the image, what I don't know how to do is to position the elements in a specific location on the image.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to make this work? I have the same issue. Thanks!